# Comparing multiple columns to one another in R, is there a use for a for loop in this case?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I'm trying to reduce the amount of coding needed to mutate a new variable based off comparing two columns at a time where I assign a value based on how the variable changes.

For example is wave_1 == wave_2 then 0, or if wave_1 == 1 & wave_2 == 2 then 1 ect....

I have a pivoted data frame that looks something like the below:

```
pidp <- c(1000,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006)
wave_1 <- c(1,2,1,3,1,1,1)
wave_2 <- c(1,2,2,3,1,1,1)
wave_3 <- c(1,2,2,3,1,1,2)
wave_4 <- c(1,2,2,1,2,2,2)

waves <- data.frame(pidp,wave_1,wave_2,wave_3,wave_4)
```

Currently I'm using an elaborate list of ifelse statements to compare the columns. Here is an example using only the first comparison column (wave_2).

```
library(dplyr)

waves <- waves %>%
  mutate(new_wave_2 = ifelse(wave_1 == wave_2,0,ifelse(wave_1==1 & wave_2 == 2,1,ifelse(wave_1 == 2 & wave_2 == 3,2,ifelse(wave_1 == 3 & wave_2 == 1,3,NA)))))
```

This has me thinking, is there a way to loop the column names to replace the replace the wave names so I don't have to retype the ifelse statement?

where the column names would assign based on a list, something like this:

```
waves <- waves %>%
  mutate(new_wave_2 = ifelse(i == i+1,0,ifelse(i==1 & i+1 == 2,1,ifelse(i == 2 & i+1 == 3,2,ifelse(i == 3 & i+1 == 1,3,NA)))))
```

Apologies if this question seems a bit basic, I'm really struggling to figure out what logic to use to solve this problem.

I"m a bit of a newbie when it comes to coding and really appreciate any help or pointers.

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: You can try with `case_when`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use the `case_when()` function which is easier to read than `if_else()` sequences. Then you can create a function to generate a new column based on the comparison you are looking for, and apply it to the different columns in a `mutate()` for example to reduce code redundancy:

```
my_function <- function(df, col_before, col_for_new){
  df <- df %>%
    mutate(new_col = case_when(
      col_before == col_for_new ~ 0,
      col_before==1 & col_for_new == 2 ~ 1,
      col_before == 2 & col_for_new == 3 ~ 2,
      col_before == 3 & col_for_new == 1 ~ 3))
  
  return(df$new_col)
}

waves %>% 
  mutate(new_wave_2 = my_function(df = ., col_before = wave_1, col_for_new = wave_2),
         new_wave_3 = my_function(df = ., col_before = wave_2, col_for_new = wave_3))
```

Comment: To make this even more efficient, you can iterative the functions over the columns with `mutate(dplyover::across2(wave_1:wave_3, wave_2:wave_4, ~ my_function(waves, .x, .y)))
`

Comment: Excellent and concise answer. Not sure how I missed the case when function until now.